# FTP server ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

Can you recommend me a good FTP server for ubuntu 9 64bit and also how to install it?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apt-get install pure-ftpd
```

conf files will be in /etc/pure-ftpd/

Answer (score 2):

Also vsftpd is very easy to install.

> sudo apt-get install vsftpd

[Ubuntu - FTP Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/serverguide/C/ftp-server.html)

Edit:

> sudo useradd ftpuser
>   sudo passwd ftpuserpassword

The path for the user will be /home/ftpuser. If you need to change it edit /etc/passwd.

To configure vsftpd to authenticate system users and allow them to upload files edit /etc/vsftpd.conf:

> local_enable=YES
>   write_enable=YES

Now restart vsftpd:

> sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart

Comment: I've installed vsftpd but I don't know how do add users and assign them a path to a directory! Can you help me?

Comment: doesn't this make every local user an ftp user, and by default, when not using ftps, this is insecure cause the password and username get sent in plain text which could later be used to access the server unless the user is chrooted?

Comment: FTP is insecure, that's a known fact. If you look at the guide I linked, you can enable ssl + restrict users and lock them in their home directories.