# How to setup FTP Server on Linux

Tags: ftp

I need to use FTP for a wordpress installation on a server and I'm not sure if it even has FTP on it.  I'm trying to install themes and things where wordpress requires the FTP info.

How can I set this up?  There doesn't seem to be much on Google or I'm just not looking in the right place

**Update**

I've added an FTP user and granted it access to where the sites are on my server.  I've also restarted apache.  I'm using `vsftpd`.  I'm still unable to connect.

Comment: What distro are you running?

Comment: What is distro?  Would Ubuntu be the right answer?

Comment: Do a search here for `ubuntu ftp server` there are quite a few questions including http://serverfault.com/questions/120134/ftp-server-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webnet,

For informational purposes, I'd use the following URL to assist you:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel-fedora-centos-vsftpd-installation.html

You can look into FTP server setup, but it sounds like you just want to get this setup pretty fast to get things rolling, so refer to my link.

Thanks,
Drew

Comment: I used that guide to install the package, but I can't find the .conf file to configure it.  I've done a `locate *.conf` and don't see it...

Comment: Did you make sure you ran `updatedb` to update the locate db file?

Comment: You updated your status stating that you are still unable to connect.  What error are you recieving?

Answer (score 0):

[vsftpd](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/)